# Redux: can I mutate state in reducer and pass new object of the same

Tags: redux, react-redux

I know that we are not suppose to mutate the state because, the app re-renders based on the fact if there has been changes in the reference in previous state and next State, but what id I do something like this

```
reducerFunction = (state, action) => {

state.value = action.value;

return {...state}

}
```

Here I am passing a new reference, so is there anything wrong with it which could happen because of state mutation

Comment: Should work but usually you do: `return { ...state, value: action.value}` and if you would do `state.value.broken=newValue` you'd still mutate `state.vaule`

Answer (score 0):

This will work but you are mutating older state and then creating new one and return it. This is not recommended. In some case this may be an issue if you need undo functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems that I can think of.

1. You would loose (or mess up) the undo history feature of redux. This comes in really handy sometimes, especially when you are dealing with lots of data.
2. You are assuming synchronous execution of the code. Redux (and JS in general) makes no such guarantees. In an application where you are updating the store with anything computer-generated (practically anything that is not user inputs) and reading it back somewhat quickly, this would mess up the state and you will have a [Race Condition](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/race-condition-critical-section-and-semaphore).

Generally, it is a good idea to follow the implementation guidelines to have your code run predictably. Sometimes there is error checking for things that are non-standard, simply because it *might* break the code. It can potentially be a security issue. I do it all the time when I write APIs.